# Apache ReverseProxy not working with Node and SSL

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup my app on HTTPS on a web server. I have a valid certificate that is installed on my InMotion host using AutoSSL. I have the node app running on my Centos server on port 3000 and my apache SSL server running on port 443. To route requests made to my website, I am attempting to create a reverse-proxy. I made a file called `default-site.conf` which is stored in `/etc/http.d/conf.d` and has the following contents:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLProxyEngine on

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com 

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full
    <Proxy *>
      Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/USER/my-app/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile  /home/USER/ssl/certs/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/USER/ssl/keys/certificate.key


    ProxyPass / https://example.com:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://example.com:3000 /

    <Directory "/home/USER/my-app/public">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>        

</VirtualHost>
```

I will emphasize that the app is accessible at `http://example.com:3000` (insecure) but when I attempt to go to `https://example.com` (secure) I get my blank index.html with a 404 error:

`[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (index.js, line 0)`

Comment: So the node app on port 3000 does not serve HTTPS, but HTTP? Perhaps you meant to ProxyPass(Reverse) to `http://example:3000/` instead of `https://example:3000/`

Comment: Also, does the node app run on the same machine as the Apache server or on another host? If it's on the same host, it might be bound to `http://localhost:3000` instead of `http://example.com:3000`, depending on how it's set up.

Comment: I had it on http before. Both run on the same machine.

Comment: Is the error the same if you proxypass to `http://`? If you just console.log all requests over at the node app, does anything come through when you make the request to `https://example.com`?

Comment: Never mind... I just said screw it and ProxyPassed without a virtual host.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix this issue by completely simplifying my config to the following two lines:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

This may not be the most flexible approach but it reroutes the traffic the way I need it to be routed, so for my purposes, it works.